# How can I convert a CSV file into a list inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I want to convert a `CSV` file into a `python Dict`, this is the format I want to achieve.

```
1,apple
1,orange
1,pearl
1,ocean
2,apple
2,pearl
3,house
4,market
4,asia
```

I would like to create something like this.

```
{
 "1":["apple","orange","pearl","ocean"],
 "2":["apple","pearl"],
 "3":["house"],
 "4":["market","asia"]
}
```

I am trying to do this in Python, could someone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

group by first column, and collect all results in a list

```py
import pandas, io

df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO("""1,apple
1,orage
1,pearl
1,ocean
2,apple
2,pearl
3,house
4,market
4,asia"""), names=["1", "2"], dtype=str)
df = df.groupby("1")["2"].apply(list).to_dict()
df
```